# Oracle Apex Validations Inline field and notification error on virtual column not showing

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with 3 columns.

```
select emp, dept, null as salary from employees ;
```

Here salary is virtual column and not the one in database.

I have a validation which throws error if Salary is less than 5000.

In the validation properties, Error: Display location is Inline field with notification
And Associated column i want it to be Salary.

But it doesn't highlight Salary in case of error.
If it is database column like EMP or DEPT it works.
Can this work for a virtual column or it is impossible?

Also if i want to highlight the entire row on erroe, is that also possible?

Comment: Your title says that error is not showing, but your description is about highlighting of column or row. Please specify your appropriate requirement or problem.